# Access is denied while executing pip -V in virtual environment in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I created a virtual environment for my development with the following commands in python 3.8 version. I also activated and upgraded pip. But while executing any command using pip, I get **Access is denied** error. Please suggest me in this case.

```
py -m venv env <= Created virtual environment name env

.\env\Scripts\activate <= Activated virtual env

python -m pip install --upgrade pip <= upgraded to Pip version 20

pip -V <= Giving Access is denied
```

Find below the image.
[image]

Comment: `pip- V` or `pip -V`? Can you please copy and paste the actual input and output?

Comment: Sir, I have added the image.

Comment: Please copy and paste the code instead of taking a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

All problems are due to latest version of **Python 3.8.1 version**. When I installed Python version 3.7.4, all worked fine. I am able to create virtual environment and also able to update pip.